# What are the locations of the Dragon Priests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I only know Krosis' location -what are the locations of the rest? Also, what should I expect when I arrive?

Comment: It's not enough for a full answer on its own, but anyone with the PC version may wish to look into [this mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=90198062), which adds a quest triggered by killing any Dragon Priest, putting map markers on the ones that remain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Hevnoraak - Located in Valthume
- Krosis - Located at the Dragon Lair Shearpoint
- Morokei - Located at Labyrinthian
- Nahkriin - Located at Skuldafn
- Otar - Located northeast of Markarth at Ragnvald
- Rahgot - Located on top of the mountain south east of Riften at Forelhost
- Vokun - Located west of Dawnstar at High Gate Ruins
- Volsung - Located at west of Solitude Volskygge

More detailed information and lore about the priests can be found here: [Dragon Priests](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest)

And for more information on their masks and related masks look here: [Dragon Priest Masks](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest_Mask)

As for what you should expect,  each priest wasn't too difficult for me to defeat but you will find that you have to defeat each one in order to receive the mask.  After you get all of the masks and take them to the shrine though, there will **not** be a priest to face in order to receive the final mask.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Marked every Dragon Priest and Word Wall location on the world map. Blue = Priest and Red = Wall]
Marked every Dragon Priest and Word Wall location on the world map. Blue = Priest and Red = Wall